# Email template translation Odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I have implemented a custom template in a custom document module which replaces the standard sale order document.

```
<!--Email template -->
<record id="sale.email_template_edi_sale" model="mail.template">
    <field name="report_template" ref="report_custom_sale_order"/>
</record>
```

This works fine but now email template is NOT translated into user/partner language (Spanish in this case). Any tip on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: To answer this question correct, we need you custom sale order document, especially the part where you call your document QWeb template.

Comment: The custom sale order document IS translated, what lost translation is the email template (which has not been modified at all)

Comment: Have you exported the translation (.po) file, for your custom module. Is the email template translation in it?

Comment: No I didn't, shall I?

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Comment: It did not work, I finally translated it via user interface

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <t t-name="account.report_invoice">
       <t t-call="report.html_container">
          <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
          <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'account.report_invoice_document')"/> </t>         </t>
</t>
```

You should add "t-raw="translate_doc" line to your Qweb report template!

Comment: As mentioned above, the custom sale order document IS actually translated, what lost translation is the email template (which has not been modified at all)

Comment: Did you try this " <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>" ?

Comment: I did, without success. I suspect that sale order mail template was not translated or that there was something funny. I did the translation manually in the GUI and it works now.